# How to dynamically modify PROTOTYPE's choice list in symfony 2 based on the underlying data

Tags: php, symfony

In my app there is *Users* which make *Payments* which are in some *Currency* (User -->> Payments <<-- Currency).

Admin can modify any **User**. I have a **User's form** with **list of his Payments** (collection) and possibility to add another *Payments* ([docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html)). When you add a Payment to this list you can choose it's currency. I want to restrict this list based on User entity of current User's form.

So I added this eventListener ([docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html)) to *Payment's* form. The problem is that it works ONLY for Payment's **entities** and not for Payment's **prototype** because `$event->getData()` results to `null` for prototype.

```
class PaymentType extends AbstractType {
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        ...

        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
            if ($payment = $event->getData()) {
                $event->getForm()->add('currency', 'entity', array(
                    'class' => 'AcmeBundle\Entity\Currency',
                    'property' => 'code',
                    'choices' => $custom_list_of_currencies_which_depends_on_underlying_user
                ));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

At this point when I modify existning *Payment* in the list I see restricted list of Currency, but when I add new *Payment* I see full list of *Currencies*.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you need event listener for this? Just pass current user directly to the form

Comment: It's not a current logged user. This is actually an arbitrary object of class User.

Comment: I'll be honest, I don't know what you mean by "Payment prototype"

Comment: read [this article](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html) if you want to know